# Java/Android.Проблемы с написанием адаптера для заполнения ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть у меня два строковых массива

```
ArrayList<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> listLink = new ArrayList<>();
```

Наполняются они динамически,Через парсинг RSS ленты.В ListTitle складывается текст,в ListLink соответсвующие тексту ссылки.
Также в коде присутствует вот такая конструкция

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (listTitle != null){
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,android.R.id.text1,listTitle);
            rssList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }
```

Она заполняет ListView,из массива ListTitle
А теперь вопрос,как мне добавить к каждому элементу LIstView,второй строкой ссылку из массива ListLink.Тоесть каждый "пункт"ListView должен содержать два TextView:В одном собсвенно текст из массива ListTitle,в другом ссылка из другого из массива ListLink. Я понимаю что мне нужно создать свой  **ArrayAdapter**,но никак не могу понять синтаксиса их создания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример для `RecyclerView`

1. Создаем класс, который будет хранить текст и ссылку. С целью
   уменьшения кода я сделал поля `public`, однако рекомендую
   сделать их `private` и реализовать `getter/setter`.

   ```
   public class Article {
       public String text;
       public String link;
   }
   ```
2. Создаем адаптер для RecyclerView. Наследуем его от
       `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

   ```
   private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

       private final List<Article> items;

       public MyAdapter(List<Article> items) {
           this.items = items;
       }

       @Override
       public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                      int viewType) {

           View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                  .inflate(R.layout.my_item_layout, parent, false);

           ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
           return vh;
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
           Article article = items.get(position)
           holder.title.setText(article.text);
           holder.link.setText(article.link);
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return items.length;
       }

       public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
           TextView title;
           TextView link;
           public ViewHolder(View v) {
               super(v);
               title = v.findViewById(R.id.title);
               link = v.findViewById(R.id.link);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Теперь все готово для подключения адаптера к `RecyclerView`

   ```
   RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
   LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
   MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(list); //передаем список полученный ранее
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Всётаки выстрел в ногу я произвёл.Правда для RecycleView.
Собственно адаптер

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final List<String> arrayList1;
private final List<String> arrayList2;

/*public MyAdapter(List<Article> items){
    this.items = items;
}*/

public MyAdapter(List<String> arraylist1, List<String> arraylist2) {
    this.arrayList1 = arraylist1;
    this.arrayList2 = arraylist2;

}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_low_it4, parent, false);


    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String text1 = arrayList1.get(position);
    String text2 = arrayList2.get(position);
    holder.textItem1.setText(text1);
    holder.textItem2.setText(text2);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList1.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textItem1;
    TextView textItem2;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        textItem1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textItem1);
        textItem2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textItem2);
    }
}
```

}

вызов Адаптера

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
rssList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(listTitle,listLink);
rssList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textItem1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textItem2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textItem1"/>
</RelativeLayout>



<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rssList">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не разобрались в примерах из интернета и не привели конкретных проблем с их постижением, то спасти вас может только передача (и соответственно отображение) всех данных в единственном `TextView` дефолтного адаптера. Для этого вам надо:

1. Создать ещё один `ArrayList<String> listTitleAndLink`
2. Заполнить его строками из `listTitle` + `перенос строки` (`"\n"`) + `listLink`
3. Передать получившийся список в конструктор дефолтного адаптера вместо `listTitle`

Answer (score 0):

Создаете класс:

```
class TitleLink {
    String title;
    String link;
}
```

Из двух списков `listTitle` и `listLink` заполняете новый `List<TitleLink>`, и передаете его в адаптер.

Comment: А ещё можно сделать двумерный массив,и другой класс создать ,как ниже и советуют,до этого я допёр.Просто был удивлён отсутствием такой очевидной возможности наполнять ListView из разных источников(массивов),без создания дополнительных юбъектов.А так как новичек ,то думал что чегото не допонимаю

Comment: @NoAppYet, наполнение из нескольких источников - это не объектно-ориентированный подход. Тем более, что это не соответствует самой идее listView, как списка.

Comment: Значит я в корне не понимаю фундаментальных основ OOП в общем,и Java  в частности.У меня уже есть два массива,их данные лежат памяти,так почему я не могу создать Adapter для обработки этих данных? Зачем мне создать ещё один массив,который будет занимать память?Не могу понять где ошибаюсь

Comment: @NoAppYet, Чтобы не занимать лишнюю память, наполняйте сразу список объектов TitleLink, а не сначала в два списка из строк, а потом в список объектов TitleLink. Никто не заставляет вас делать правильно, делайте любыми костылями, какими хотите.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю сразу забыть о ListView. Используйте  RecyclerView.
Тут подробно расписано как его завести. http://www.fandroid.info/primer-ispolzovaniya-cardview-i-recyclerview-v-android/
Так же по ссылке есть исходники проекта.

И да, советую сразу выделить отдельную сущность, а не таскать данные в разных списках, это существенно упростит вам жизнь!

Например так

```
class RssItem {
    String mTitle;
    String mLink;
}
```

Comment: со вчерашнего дня смотрю  в сторону  RecyclerView.